# Who Are The Employers and Where Are They Located?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

I like the Careers site, and I agree that the cost of posting my CV is pretty low, but I live in the UK and don't want to waste my hard earned GBP if all the employers are based in the US.

Is there some way you can give an indication (even if it's at a high level) of where your current employers are based, what they're generally looking for, and how frequently?

On my homepage for Careers I see the number of employers and the number of searches. I'd be more likely to pay if I could see "Employers In Your Region" "Employers Looking For Your Skills". Basically, it would be good to see stats that say "Hey - if you were to file your CV then it wouldn't be in vain"

**update**

I blame snow blindness, but I've only just spotted that next to the "Total Searches" stat on the home page there is a "show more detail" link that exposes some of the information I was looking for.

Comment: no blindness, that feature is only a few hours old

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We now have **public employer search statistics** for CV holders, under the stats tab -- just click "show detail>>" to expand.

This list is queried dynamically about every hour, and reflects current live data.

[image]

Comment: woah! just filed the CV yesterday, mostly out of curiosity (I'm currently employed, but you know... postdoc contracts do run out very often). It's a very beautiful service what you implemented, and I really appreciate the strong focus on usability.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. This goes a significant way towards what I was looking for. How long as this been there? Have I simply overlooked it?

Comment: Nice addition. Not as much a "black box" any longer.

Comment: And... France is obviously boycotting this evil site :-]

Answer (score 3):

The thing is the employers are generally transient, with pricing packages working on a weekly basis for them.

On careers, prospective programmers are long-term users and employers are short-term. So while it wouldn't hurt to have a listing of some employer statistics those statistics are likely to change dramatically on a regular basis and so probably wouldn't be a good basis for determining whether or not to sign up for careers.

On the other hand, if the statistics included all previous employers as well as current ones, then the data would be more useful for your purpose but wouldn't really reflect what employers are actually on careers at any given time.

---

**EDIT**: A good idea might be to allow users to search for employer information. Not necessarily details about who is on, but something like a query that lets you search for employers by both region and most recent activity.

That way you can verify that there are active employers in your region or, if you're thinking more long-term, that there *were* active employers in your region which implies there will be employers there again.

Comment: Yeah. A fuzy warm feeling that there are, or were, employers in my region and skill set would be good enough.

Comment: @Martin: Agreed. Your comment proved to be inspiration for my edit.

Comment: Your suggestion in the edit sounds perfect.

Comment: Perfect, yet I doubt we'll see it implemented.

Answer (score 3):

Would it be possible to produce a world map showing where recent jobs (or employer searches) are located? This information could fade over time, so that searches performed last week on a particular region are less dominant than searches going on today.  Assembled into a time-lapse video, it could be quite valuable seeing how hot spots move around the world over time.

Something similar could possibly be used to show the most popular technologies, although obviously some other sort of graphical representation would need to be used than a map.

Answer (score 0):

This new feature (show details) is nice but my country is not on that list. I still don't know if there are any employers from my country.
I've been listed for 1 week and didn't get single search hit.